# Error: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta

Tags: html

This line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
```

is causing this error in Firebug:

```
Error: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
```

Why? How can I fix it?

Btw. I am using HTML 5 doctype like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Apache, add this to your root .htaccess file:

```
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"
```

Check this article for more info on the error: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/x-ua-compatible_and_html5/

Comment: If I do it I get an Internal Server Error

Comment: Are you trying this local or online?

Comment: This seems to be a known problem and probably won't occur online: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,54851,54851#msg-54851

Answer (score 1):

You can try to solve it with PHP (source here : http://www.validatethis.co.uk/news/fix-bad-value-x-ua-compatible-once-and-for-all/ ).

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) &&
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
    header('X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1');
```

It worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Firebug.  Since IE is the only browser that needs the meta tag, you could wrap the meta tag in an IE conditional block.

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
<![endif]-->
```